# Regex to restrict only one occurrence of open and close brackets using C#

Tags: c#, regex

How to make sure I don't allow more than one brackets "(" and ")" in the input text?
I have the following expression that will allow numbers, spaces, hyphens and brackets.

```
Regex.Match(text, @"^[0-9 (,),-]+$").Success
```

I don't what to allow something like "((123) 456-7891 or (91)123-23123(1). The correct string can be: "(123) 1231231 or (121)123-213123.

Edited:
Sorry for not being clear. Requirement is to only allow numbers, spaces, hyphens and brackets (one set only). To be specific, "(" should always have a closing bracket ")". As one of you said no paren or one set of paren. If someone can also tell how to allow the paren at any position not only at the start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do it:

```
@"^(?:[^()]*|[^()]*\([^()]*\)[^()]*)$"
```

and only allowing numbers, hyphens and spaces:

```
@"^(?:[-0-9 ]*|[-0-9 ]*\([-0-9 ]*\)[-0-9 ]*)$"
```

This basically says that either there are no parens, or there can be only one set of parens. If you only want strings that have exactly one set of parens, you can use this simpler form:

```
@"^[^()]*\([^()]*\)[^()]*$"
```

and only allowing numbers, hyphens and spaces:

```
@"^[-0-9 ]*\([-0-9 ]*\)[-0-9 ]*$"
```

Comment: Great but how to make sure only numbers, spaces and hyphens are included.

Comment: Updated with patterns that allow only numbers, spaces and hyphens as you requested.

Comment: Michael, this is wonderful stuff. I used - @"^(?:[-0-9 ]*|[-0-9 ]*\([-0-9 ]*\)[-0-9 ]*)$" and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
^[^\(\)]*\([^\(\)]*\)[^\(\)]*$
```

worked for me based on your examples. This will not, however, ensure that the rest of the phrase is numbers. for instance, this regex will match both `(123) 1231231` and `abc(def)ghi` Let me know if this is ok.

Comment: Need only numbers, spaces, hyphens and parens.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking and what you want are probably two different things :-)
Some examples:

- 1231234(12)
- 1231234
- )1231234
- (123412

Are they legal?

Start with this:

Legal:

- 123456
- 1234-456
- (123)345
- (123) 345
- (123)345-678
- (123) 345 678

Regex:

```
@"^(\(\[0-9]+\) ?)?\[0-9]+(-\[0-9]+)?$"
```

Comment: you are right, I have not edited the post. By the way, how to make sure that the parens are anywhere in the string. meaning it can be at the start or in middle?

Answer (score 1):

If it's always open-bracket followed by 3 numbers, then close-bracket, put that into the regex:

```
@"^\(\d{3}\)\s?\d{3}-?\d{4}$"
```

That is, open-bracket, three numbers, close bracket, optional space, three numbers, optional hyphen, four numbers.

Comment: Note that \d will match the numbers from other character sets, and \s will match tabs and other "strange" spaces (nbsp for example)

Comment: Yes, Xantos is right. But thanks for the response. I need to allow paren at any position but ")" should follow "(".

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for the above instances you specified:

```
Regex.Match(text, @"^\([0-9]{3}\)\s?[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]+$").Success
```

This will match any number of digits at the end of the string. You did not specify how many are allowed.  If you wanted to make this more specific you could replace the last + sign with {4,6} where 4 is the minimum number of digits after the - and 6 is the maximum.

Comment: I have edited the post. Need to check for parens anywhere in the string but only one set.