# Method for checking corresponding open/close "brackets"

Tags: java, regex, libraries, brackets

I am writing a sample application in which I've came across the following problem:

I have to check to characters in terms of their "compatibility".

```
boolean checkIfPairCorrect(Character c1, Character c2) {...}
```

In a nutshell it is sth like: "Check if these characters make correct open-close pair".
For example:

Pair "(" and ")"  returns TRUE
Pair "{" and "}"  returns TRUE
Pair "(" and "}"  returns FALSE   // incompatibile brackets
Pair ")" and "("  returns FALSE   // wrong order 
Pair "a" and "3"  returns FALSE   // 'a' or '3' are not the characters for which "closing" char can be found

You would say: "Simply write a regexp man!!!" using some Internet help like:

[Regular Expression to match outer brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-outer-brackets)
[Regex to restrict only one occurrence of open and close brackets using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997469/regex-to-restrict-only-one-occurrence-of-open-and-close-brackets-using-c-sharp)
[Regexp and brackets article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

And you would be right, but...
The problem is difficult for me because function can take some exotic characters as parameters (UTF-8 encoding) like japanese, turkish, arabic etc. I do not know what characters can be treated as open-close pair in other languages(cultures), so I am looking for a library which can deal with my problem.

Question: *Do you know any library which could be helpful in my case, or do you have any tips how to deal with it?*

Comment: I'd think that after [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/546457/335858) it would be clear that you cannot do it in regexp, even theoretically: the regexp model does not support counting. That's a wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight this is not about parsing longer text, this is about finding pair for a character. And you can certainly do that with a regexp.

Comment: @hyde Yes, you are right.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Unicode has character classes `Ps` (opening bracket characters) and `Pe` (closing bracket characters). But I don't know any way to check if they match.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Ok... my digresion about regex was not a good idea (in my app I will use it, but it is not relevant as far as this question is concerned)

Answer (score 3):

Why not have a map like this:

```
Map<Character, Character> pairs = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
pairs.put('(', ')');
pairs.put('{', '}');
pairs.put('[', ']');
...
```

Then your method could be

```
boolean checkIfPairCorrect(char c1, char c2) {
    return pairs.get(c1) == c2;
}
```

Comment: was about to recommend same, you were too fast! :-)

Comment: Yeah yeah... That's of course right, but the question is if you know any library which has all pairs ready to use... I mean which "konws" for instance all possible open-close pairs UTF-8 encoding ;)

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here's how you can do this with regexp:

```
boolean checkIfPairCorrect(Character c1, Character c2) {
    String str = c1.toString() + c2.toString();
    return str.matches(
          "(\\[\\])"
       + "|(\\(\\))"
       + "|({})"
       // ... add any more you may want 
       );
}
```

But I would do it using a map, as shown by A.R.S's answer.

About your actual question, I don't know if there's a library, and I don't think eg. unicode has some neat way to determine thise pairs. So your best bet might be to use the map method, and hard-code the pairs yourself, perhaps from [the list in this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Encoding).